Error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON' when Fetching Internal API for SSG with NextJS AppRouter on Vercel
I have a Next.js application with the following code:
export default async function StaticSiteGenerator() {
  const res = await fetch(`https://{DOMAIN_NAME}/api/data`);
  const data = await res.json();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Pokémon List</h1>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
        {data.map((data: any, index: any) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{data.id}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


When I deploy this Next.js app to Vercel, I encounter the following error during the build process:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5584:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5555:27)
    at fullyReadBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1665:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async specConsumeBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5564:7)
    at async i (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/extra/ssg/page.js:1:4401) {
  digest: '3318096297'
}

I prefer to use the internal API (rather than server actions or other alternatives). How can I resolve this issue and ensure a successful build?
I suspect that this error occurs because the internal API is not ready at the time of the fetch request during the build process. Interestingly, the build works fine locally.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Not really much to go with but one suggestion is to ensure that .../api/data is sending JSON data and not some page of data.  Go to that data url and see what the results are.

Thank you for the suggestion. I have confirmed that the URL .../api/data returns JSON data correctly when accessed locally.

/api/data if you are using internal API, add the API url like this and try

When using /api/data, I get the error: "Internal error: TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/data."
The Next.js documentation states that fetch should be written as const staticData = await fetch(https://...) with the URL specified.

I'm assuming that DOMAIN_NAME refers to the same Next.js app?
If so the issue is that while deploying on Vercel you are server rending your app and the API endpoint is not available yet.
Locally it works because fetch is cached between dev mode runs, so the endpoint is available, but this is not the case when deploying.
In server components you are already running on the server, so you should access the data directly rather than calling your API. You already have the privileged access of running on the server.
If needed you can DRY up data handlers between your API and your server component to ensure they execute the same way. For example
export default async function StaticSiteGenerator() {
  // move your retrieval logic into getPokemon and use it
  // in your API route also
  const data = await getPokemon();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Pokémon List</h1>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
        {data.map((data: any, index: any) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{data.id}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

To summarize:

For server components, don't fetch your own API routes or route handlers, just retrieve data directly
For client components fetch from your API per normal

More context & details here.
